# Can I use a string as the key in a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

Can I use a string as the key in a JavaScript object?

```
var method,
    obj;

method = function () {
  return "foo";
};

// works
obj = {
  'foo': 'bar'
};

// does not work
obj = {
  method(): 'bar'
};
```

Comment: In ES6 `obj={[method()]:'bar'}`, in ES5 `obj={};obj[method()]='bar'`

Comment: not with literals, but with vars

Comment: Curse you JavaScript!

Comment: I just used bracket notation. It works, but it's ugly and disorganized. Oh well.

Comment: Regarding the duplication: I agree, Bergi, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327/2535178) is the most concise answer. I needed to ask the question in more precise terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that way.

You CAN do this:

```
function doStuff() {
  return "foo";
};

var obj = {}
  ;

obj[doStuff()] = 'bar';
```

And on the subject of methods and subscripting...

This would appear to work, but it's a bad idea and it doesn't work how you might think:

```
var obj = {}
  ;

obj[doStuff] = 'bar';
```

What happens is `doStuff` will coerse  as `doStuff.toString()` and it would sometimes behave as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use square bracket syntax in javascript. 
This cannot be done when declaring an object literal though. You will have to do something like the following.

```
obj = {}; 
obj[method()] = "bar";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you create an empty object first,
then call the method as if it was the key,
it will assign it how you want it to.

```
var method = function() {
    return 'bar';
};

var obj = {};

obj[method()] = 'bar';
```